# Как правильно переименовать проект Django и приложение в нем?

Tags: python, django

Решил изменить название проекта и проложения в Django, но не получилось. Выдает ошибку:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'site.urls'; 'site' is not a package

В этих местах изменил название с project1 на website, а app1 на site:

manage.py:

```py
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'website.settings')
```

asgi.py:

```py
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'website.settings')
```

wsgi.py:

```py
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'website.settings')
```

urls.py:

```py
path('', include('site.urls'))
```

settings.py:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = ['site']
ROOT_URLCONF = 'website.urls'
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'website.wsgi.application'
```

apps.py:

```py
class siteConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'site'
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Покажите структуру файлов и папок, в частности что такое site

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XO97Y.png "site" это название приложения

Comment: Что-то странное. А если рядом с manage.py создать какой-нибудь ещё файл, для пробы написать в нём `import site; print(site)` и запустить — что выведет?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZd4G.png

Comment: А, я осознал — [site это же встроенный модуль питона](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html), нельзя создавать свои модули с таким же названием, переименуйте во что-нибудь другое (что не совпадает с названиями встроенных модулей)

Comment: Спасибо большое, заработало

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя использовать встроеные модули в качестве название проекта или же приложения; один из них "site"